# Limit network bandwith per container with OpenVZ

Tags: centos, containers, iptables, bandwidth, openvz

I want to limit network usage per container (e.g. upload and download thresholds). Can I do that via configuration or via `vzctl` somehow to set constraints on sent/received traffic?

I've found documentation on [traffic shaping](https://docs.openvz.org/openvz_users_guide.webhelp/_setting_rate_and_ratebound_parameters.html) but there is no `prctl` utility installed on my system. Is there a way to install it manually on Centos (`Linux version 2.6.32-042stab140.4 (kbuild-rh6-x64) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) )`) or what's the right method of setting such a limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found [this solution](https://github.com/FastVPSEestiOu/openvz-network-shaper/blob/master/fastvps_openvz_shaper.pl) based on [tc utility](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) which does the job.